# Differences is PHP\SQL Return

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have two functions:

```
    function display_name1($s){
        global $db;
        $query1 = "SELECT Taken From Alcohol where P_Key = $s";
        $r = $db->prepare($query1);
        $r->execute();
        $result = $r->fetchColumn();
        return $result;

}

    function write_Recipe($s){
        global $db;
        $query1 = "SELECT Taken From Alcohol where Name = $s";
        $r = $db->prepare($query1);
        $r->execute();
        $result = $r->fetchColumn();
        return $result;

    }
```

The only difference is that I'm matching the input "$s" with "P_Key" in the first example, and "Name" in the latter. When I put in a number for the first function, I get the appropriate return. When I put in a string that matches at least one "Name", I get nothing back. It seems to not be matches the strings for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: You're also missing a table name in the second query

Comment: That's weird, the table name exists in my current code. I don't know how it didn't make it into the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **syntax error** in the SQL query. You are missing the table name in the second query:

```
"SELECT Taken From where Name = '$s'"
```

Should be something like:

```
"SELECT Taken FROM `tablename` WHERE  `Name` = '$s'"
```

---

Further note, that if you already using prepared statements, you should bind variables to the query instead of building the query using string concatination. Also the usage of `global` isn't perfect for an OOP design. Here comes an example how it can be done better:

```
// extend a class from PDO
class CustomPDO extends PDO {


   public function display_name($s){

       // use placeholder :p_key in query
       $query1 = "SELECT Taken FROM `Alcohol` WHERE `P_Key` = :p_key";
       $r = $this->prepare($query1);

       // bind value to prepared statement
       $r->execute(array(
           ':p_key' => $s
       ));
       $result = $r->fetchColumn();
       return $result;
   }

   public function write_recipe($s){

       // use placeholder :name in query
       $query1 = "SELECT Taken FROM `tablename` WHERE  `Name` = :name";

       // use $this as we are extended from PDO
       $r = $this->prepare($query1);

       // bind value to prepared statement
       $r->execute(array(
           ':name' => $s
       ));

       $result = $r->fetchColumn();
       return $result;
   }
}
```

Then use the class like a regular PDO object:

```
$db = new CustomPDO($connection_string, $user, $password);
```

But having two additional methods:

```
$result = $db->display_name('foo');
$result = $db->write_recipe('foo');
```

Comment: Are you crazy to downvote me because of this?! Yes, I would not do it. But it is not *wrong*. Issuing a query with syntax errors is *just wrong*

Comment: @Phil While it's technically not good practice, the discussion of how to best do SQL isn't really the issue at hand. OP just wanted his query(ies) fixed.

EDIT: While Wrikken's answer is very good, it kind of skipped over the part about what error was actually occurring, and just corrected it without mentioning it.

Comment: I'll also give you a +1, even though I beat you by a minute :P

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. 

Though I am confused as to why concatenating values for SQL query is "wrong" or even "inadvisable". How else am I to run queries based off of user input?

Answer (score 2):

When querying on strings,  you should surround a variable with quotes, like so:

`"SELECT Taken From where Name = '$s'"`

Also your second query is missing a table name.

`"SELECT Taken From`TableName`where Name = '$s'"`

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, but when I added in the quotes on "Name" like the above answer (that you beat by a minute) it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Strings need to be quoted (and probably escaped if you haven't already). You seem to be using PDO, why not add a placeholder ? and execute `execute(array($s));` instead, making PDO do the work for you?

```
function display_name1($s){
    global $db;
    $query1 = "SELECT Taken From Alcohol where P_Key = ?";
    $r = $db->prepare($query1);
    $r->execute(array($s));
    $result = $r->fetchColumn();
    return $result;
}

function write_Recipe($s){
    global $db;
    $query1 = "SELECT Taken From Alcohol where Name = ?";
    $r = $db->prepare($query1);
    $r->execute(array($s));
    $result = $r->fetchColumn();
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: While you're cleaning up the code, why not pass the `PDO` object in as a function argument rather than using globals?

Comment: Because I don't know whether the `$db` object is in scope at the point of function call :P (but yeah, you have a point about that being better).

Comment: It would be in scope if passed to the function

Comment: @hek2mgl You're joking, right? - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-995

Comment: Better yet would even be an object instantiated with a required `PDO` implementing object in its constructor set as property, so instance methods can use the properties and not bother every single function with a $db argument. I get what you're saying, I approve of it, but we have to little information of the OPs application as a whole to start rewriting that willy-nilly.

Comment: This is my first legitimate PHP website, so I guess I'm not as familiar with it as I'd like to be. I'm creating a system where if a person writes down that they are bringing an ingredient, it will display in the recipes section of the site. Right now, I'm just passing the name of a foreign key so that I can reference whether the ingredient is being taken, so how would that single variable be an array?

Comment: @MarcelMarino: the array in `execute()` you mean? Look at docs of PDOStatement::fetch() to see it's arguments. And a helpful pointer if you're starting: avoid globals as much as possible if you can. What looks like a quick working fix now can seriously hinder you later on. Dependancy Injection patterns (google it) are much preferred if your projects become more complex.